# HSTS blocks googlebot

Tags: googlebot, hsts

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
</ifModule>
```

Except google indexing has stopped since implementation. Does anyone have a work-around?

Comment: There is no issue with the setting you are currently showing. There is probably another issue. Using Google Webmasters Tools, have Google crawl your site and it will tell you if there are any errors. The option is under Crawl > Fetch as Google

Comment: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/index-status?hl=en&siteUrl=https://www.denverprophit.us/ GWT was setup with the HTTPS protocol since it's going to redirect bots and humans, anyway. @David

Comment: I'm saying use the "Fetch as Google" tool and it will tell you exactly what your site is replying with and why Google can't reach your site or why it won't crawl it.